# Bulk insert from txt. file with primary key and Timestamp values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, bulkinsert, identity-insert

I have a table called `Address` which has an `AddressID` as the primary key (auto-incremented value), it also has a `tmsp` column which is of type `TimeStamp`.

I created a stored procedure that deletes records from the table but before deleting, I save the records to a `.txt` file. And in the process of saving the records into the text file, I convert the timestamp to a `Varbinary` value. Meaning that `tmsp` column is saved as `Varbinary` in the text file.

Now I create a new stored procedure to insert the deleted records back into the database the code as below:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
BEGIN
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Address ON
    SET @SQL = N'BULK INSERT Address
                 FROM ''' + @Address + '''
                 WITH (
                        FIRSTROW = 2,
                        FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
                        ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
                      )'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Address OFF
 END
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 273, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CleanUp_Address, Line 43 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.

When I remove the `IDENTITY_INSERT` it inserts the data into the table as new value so the `AddressID` is overwritten, but that is not what I want. I need to keep the `AddressID`.

Any ideas?

Comment: First, TIMESTAMP is, and has been, deprecated for quite some time. You should be using ROWVERSION. But you will need to avoid inserting value for that column and, to do that, you need a format file. Discussion (which you should have found by searching first) [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d8d5fbe4-a0bd-44b2-b6d4-3d912c8ed180/how-to-bulk-insert-data-to-table-with-timestamp-column?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Comment: I hope that `@Address` isn't an SP parameter, or similar; otherwise this is a huge injection problem.

Comment: @SMor The database is old and I can't change the schema now. I have to live with the TIMESTAMP

Comment: Is is possible that what I need is to convert the varbinary that is saved in the txt file into a TIMESTAMP value then insert it to the Address table?

Comment: `TIMESTAMP`/ `ROWVERSION` type columns are **system-internal** binary counters - they **CANNOT** with any method, trick, hack, or workaround be set from the outside.

Comment: @marc_s, I think you misunderstood my question. I don't want to change timestamp, all what I need is to do Bulk insert where I insert deleted records into address table again.

Comment: IF you do a **BULK INSERT**, **all** columns will be attempted to be filled  - you cannot restrict that. Therefore, the BULK INSERT will also attempt to fill in values for your `TIMESTAMP` column - which will fail - always. So you'll need to bulk insert into a separate "staging" table *without* the `timestamp` column, and once completed, insert/update your "real" table from the staging table